# Docker container detected! Ruxit Agent cannot be installed

Tags: docker

I try to install Ruxit inside docker but I got this extremely strange error?

My dockerfile

```
RUN wget -O ruxit-Agent-Linux-1.91.271.sh https://yjm50779.live.ruxit.com/installer/agent/unix/latest/hnaT75uwgZzoBEf7
RUN /bin/sh ruxit-Agent-Linux-1.91.271.sh
```

Error:

```
Docker container detected! Ruxit Agent cannot be installed inside docker container. Setup won't continue.
```

Comment: Sounds like a good question for the folks at ruxit.

Comment: Can you provide your complete Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question! As the error message indicates, you can indeed not install Ruxit Agent inside a Docker container. Now Ruxit does support Docker, so how come you cannot install inside a container?

**Ruxit Agent needs to be installed directly on the host operating system** and it will detect and monitor any docker containers that you start there - **no need to modify any of your existing Docker images.** We like to think this is a pretty cool approach.

### But what if you just can't install anything on the host operating system?

Then we are currently working on two options for you:

1. We will soon publish a **Docker image with Ruxit Agent pre-installed on dockerhub**. If you start this image as a privileged Docker container, Ruxit Agent will automatically monitor all other containers running on the same host - again without modifying any other container image. This option is useful, if you want to roll out Ruxit Agent e.g. with Mesos, Docker Swarm or Kubernetes.
2. We are working on **Ruxit Agent for Platform as a Service** deployments, where you do not have root access to the host where your application is running. In this scenario, you need to copy the files of Ruxit agent into you Docker container and modify the startup parameters of e.g. your JVM to load Ruxit Agent into the process you want to monitor.

Both these options will be released within the next couple of weeks, [check our blog](https://blog.ruxit.com/) to be the first to know. If you want to try them a bit earlier, let us know at success@ruxit.com and we will set you up with an early access preview as soon as we have something ready.